# Firefox displaying error messages

Tags: windows, firefox, activex

My Firefox 3.6.3 started displaying weird error messages when I load pretty much every page (a few per page):

```
---------------------------
ActiveX Error
---------------------------
Could not create the control {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}. Check that it has been installed on your computer and that this page correctly references it.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Any ideas how can I locate which plugin, add-on etc. is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Disable all add-ons and one by one start reactivating them... Once you get the error again, you know that last one you reactivated is the culprit.

Comment: Didn't help :(. Does it mean its a problem with one of the plugins?

Comment: If all the add-ons are disabled and your browser still displays errors, it means it's not an add-on issue. Try removing Firefox and re-installing it.